# Finding the differential equation given certain solutions

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, curves

I'm stuck at this exercise of my notes:

> Find the differential equation that has the solutions:
>
> $$\phi_1= e^{2t}
> (13\cos{t}, −26\sin{ t}, −26 \sin {t})$$
>   $$\phi_2= 7e^{2t}(−2 \cos{t} − 3 \sin {t}, −6 \cos{t} + 4 \sin {t}, −6 \cos{t} + 4 \sin {t}) + 2e^{−3t}(7, 8, 34)$$
>   $$\phi_3=e^{2t}(\sin {t}, 2 \cos{t}, 2 \cos{t})$$

It's the first exercise on my notes like this. How do we usually attack this kind of exercises? What's the procedure to follow?

Answer (score 1):

Note that the $\phi_i$ are functions of vectors in $3$ dimensions. Differentiate the $\phi_i$ wrt $t$ component-wise, possibly more than once. Then eliminate $t$ from these equations to get three equations in terms of the $\phi_i$ and their  derivatives. Then by having $$\phi=(\phi_1,\phi_2,\phi_3),$$ and its derivatives defined similarly in terms of their components, you have the equation you seek in terms of $\phi$ and its derivatives.

NB. It will be messy, but it's worth trying.

Comment: There has to be another way to "formally" solve this kind of exercises, this is almost trial and error.

Comment: No. This is not trial and error. Have you actually tried anything? Did you understand my explanation above? If you've been doing problems like this as you say in the OP, then the basic difference here is that you have a function of a vector instead of a scalar. That something is long and messy doesn't make it trial and error. There's no royal road to learning.

Comment: It actually won't be that messy. The components are in terms of sinusoidal and exponential functions and constants, whose derivatives are pretty nice. As you work, you should be able to see patterns so that the equation may not be of order higher than $2$.

Answer (score 1):

There are infinitely many systems  of ODEs of the form
$$\dot x_i(t)=f_i\bigl(t, x_1(t),x_2(t), x_3(t)\bigr)\qquad(1\leq i\leq3),$$ all of them having $\infty^3$ solutions $t\mapsto\phi(t)\in{\mathbb R}^3$, among them the three special $\phi_j$ in your list. The simplest such system is the following:

Your three vector-valued functions $\phi_j$ are solutions of a homogeneous linear system with constant coefficients of the following kind:
$$\left[\matrix{\dot x_1\cr\dot x_2\cr\dot x_3\cr}\right] =\left[\matrix{a_{11}&a_{12}&a_{13}\cr a_{21}&a_{22}&a_{23}\cr a_{31}&a_{32}&a_{33}\cr}\right] \left[\matrix{x_1\cr x_2\cr x_3\cr}\right]\ .$$
"Normally" the constant matrix $[A]=[a_{ik}]$ would be given; but here it is unknown, and we have to determine it from the givens. This can be done in the following way: Compute the column vectors $[\dot\phi_j]$. The three vector equations
$$[\dot\phi_j(t)]=[A]\,[\phi_j(t)]\qquad(1\leq j\leq3)$$
then expand to nine scalar identities in $t$ involving the matrix elements $a_{ik}$ in a linear way. Comparing coefficients of like terms $e^{-2t}\cos t$, $\>e^{-2t}\sin t$, $\>e^{-3t}$ should then allow you to determine the $a_{ik}$.